# Resize a circle in android when User Moves touchscreen

Tags: android

I'm trying to draw a resizable Circle in android with user Touch events.

I need that when user touch the scree, the circle will be drawn, then if he moves the finger outter of its center the circle will be go bigger and vice versa, how can i do that??

Also, he is like redrawing the circle, that's because in the ACTION_MOVE there is this sentence that says:

canvas.drawCircle(...)

But how can i work with the starting circle and make it bigger or smaller??

I have already tried a lot of things(for like 6 hours) and I don't know what else to try, this is my current code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            cacheCanvas.drawCircle(event.getX(),event.getY(),50,paint);
            pX= event.getX();
            pY = event.getY();
            circleDiam = (event.getX()+event.getY())/2;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            cacheCanvas.drawCircle(event.getX(),event.getY(),(event.getX()+event.getY())/2,paint);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;
    }
    invalidate();

    return true;
}
```

This is the result i got:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0y7s.png

Very thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a SurfaceView to draw the circle and then 
listen to the touch events on the surface view.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html

There are some very good examples of using surface views available online
if you google for them.

If you only have a couple of sizes and you want to go cheesy on it you could define drawables and swap them in as the user drags. This would not be graceful or smooth.

Comment: The user can choose several shapes like straight lines, circles, rectangles and text, and combine them if he needs to, and i want that he can resize whatever shape based on his needs